# JPanel with FlowLayout not Appearing

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I am using the following code for placing labels inside a JPanel, but the JPanel is not appearing (instead, only a blank JFrame is appearing).

Below is the class creating a JFrame instance.

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main { 

public static void main(String[] args){

    WindowContents window = new WindowContents();

    window.setSize(600, 400);
    window.setVisible(true);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}

}
```

Below is the class for setting the contents of the JFrame.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class WindowContents extends JFrame {

JLabel label1;
JLabel label2;
JLabel label3;

JPanel panel1;

public WindowContents(){

    super("Label Display 2.0");

    panel1 = new JPanel();
    panel1.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 40, 40));
    panel1.setVisible(true);

    label1 = new JLabel("Label1");
    panel1.add(label1);

    label2 = new JLabel("Label2");
    panel1.add(label2);

    label3 = new JLabel("Label3");
    panel1.add(label3);


}

}
```

Are there any ideas how to make the JPanel contents appear? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> how to make the JPanel contents appear?

Add panel in the frame.

```
public WindowContents(){
    super("Label Display 2.0");
    panel1 = new JPanel();
    ...
    add(panel1);
}
```

---

Note:

- Use `frame.pack()` instead of `frame.setSize()` that fits the components as per component's preferred size.
- There is no need to call `panel1.setVisible(true);`
- Just call `frame.setVisible(true)` in the end after adding all the component.
- [Favor Composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance). Instead of extending `JFrame` make it as member of `WindowContents` class.
- Use [SwingUtilities.invokeLater()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29) or [EventQueue.invokeLater()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29)  to make sure that [EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) is initialized properly.

Answer (score 0):

you  haven't added the panel to the frame, here's how your class WindowsContents end:

```
    class WindowContents extends JFrame {

    JLabel label1;
    JLabel label2;
    JLabel label3;

    JPanel panel1;

    public WindowContents(){

        super("Label Display 2.0");

        panel1 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 40, 40));

        label1 = new JLabel("Label1");
        panel1.add(label1);

        label2 = new JLabel("Label2");
        panel1.add(label2);

        label3 = new JLabel("Label3");
        panel1.add(label3);

        add(panel1);

    }
}
```

Cheers

Comment: It took you 12 minutes to post an answer which has already been posted, yet adds no additional value?